# Read data from CSV file and convert one box of data to JSON Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: json, csv, powershell, webrequest

In CSV file with 3 columns (Method, URL, Body) and data as below (`inputdata.csv`):

```
POST  https://xyz/abc  {phoneNumber=@{number='2222222' areaCode='345'}}
```

Below is the powershell code:

```
$ServiceDetails = Import-Csv .\inputdata.csv
foreach ($ServiceDetail in $ServiceDetails)
{$full = "@" + $ServiceDetail.Body 
$Body = $full | ConvertTo-Json
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method $ServiceDetail.Method -Uri $ServiceDetail.URL -Headers $RequestHeader -Body $Body }
```

When executed, I get the below error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Bad Request","uuid":"1132131"}
```

When I checked the `$Body` it hasn't converted to JSON format. It looks like this:

```
"@{phoneNumber=@{number=\u00272222222\u0027\nareaCode=\u0027345\u0027}}"
```

How can I convert the data from CSV to JSON?

Comment: Is that text an good example? It is not good Json even with the `@`. String s should be quoted and : instead of equals.

Comment: `{"phoneNumber": {"number": "2222222","areaCode": "345"}}` [passed validation as json](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: you'll need a ; between number and areacode as well as use invoke-expression.

invoke-expression "@{phoneNumber=@{number='2222222';areaCode='345'}}" | convertto-json

Answer (score 0):

@AnthonyStringer suggested the solution here. The problems are two fold here. First, you are running `ConvertTo-Json` against a string, not an object, so it has nothing to convert. Second, your string is not properly formatted to be a valid object, so we can't even convert it to one for it to then be converted to JSON. Let's start at the top though. The way to convert the string into a hashtable is simple, you run the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet on it as such:

```
"@" + $ServiceDetail.Body | Invoke-Expression
```

Now, if the string is a valid expression it processes it. In this case you want it to be a pair of hashtables, but the inner hashtable isn't right. It's missing a semi-colon between the first and second key/value pairs. How do you fix that? Man, that's a tough one. Improperly formatted code is difficult since the errors may not always be consistent. Now since we're working with hashtables we could probably run it through a regex to find key/value pairs, split them into an array, and then join the array with semicolons. Actually, that sounds like a fairly good idea, so let's do that. This gets a bit convoluted, but hopefully you can follow along here. I'm going to go from the point where you just defined `$full`, though for our purposes I'm going to just set `$full` to the string in your example.

```
$full = "@{phoneNumber=@{number='2222222' areaCode='345'}}"
$body = ([regex]"^.*?@\{((?:(?:\w+)=(?:'.*?')\s?)+)}.*$").matches($full)|%{
    $Fixed = ($_.Groups[1].value -split "((?:\w+)=(?:'.*?'))" -join ';').trim(';')
    $_.value -replace [regex]::escape($_.Groups[1].value), "$Fixed"
}|Invoke-Expression|ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Ok, `$body` now has the value of:

```
{"phoneNumber":{"areaCode":"345","number":"2222222"}}
```

That's valid JSON, and you should be all set. Now, this could have been simpler if I made some assumptions like 'all nested hashtables will have the exact same content format of **number='#######' areaCode='###'** but that seemed like a bad idea since you only gave us one example line, and other lines could contain almost anything for all we knew. So, this should work for whatever you have to fix it assuming they're just hashtables with key/value pairs that are only separated by a space.

If somebody else sees a good way to simplify that code please feel free!